# How can I get both PDO exceptions and the other ones?

Tags: php, pdo, exception, try-catch

I have a script like this:

```
try {
    $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT .. SELECT query");
    $stm->execute();
    if ( $stm->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        echo 'inserted';
    } else {
        throw new Exception('No rows inserted');
    }
} catch(Exception $e) { 
    echo $e;
}
```

As you see that `catch` block just accesses `Exception`s that I've set. Actually I need to also access PDO exception. Something like this:

```
} catch(Exception $e, PDOException $pdo) {
    echo  isset($pdo) ?  "other message: " . $e   : null;
    echo  isset($e)   ?  "PDO message: "   . $pdo : null;
}
```

As you know my current syntax is wrong. I'm talking about `catch(Exception $e, PDOException $pdo)`. Well is there any workaround?

Comment: You can throw a PDO Exception instance , and in catch block only process PDOException.  like   try { throw new PDOException('No rows inserted')} catch (PDOException $e) { echo $e->getErrorMessage }

Comment: `Exception` will also catch `PDOException`, since the latter inherits from the former.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the Q. Your catch block is already setup to catch a PDOException if it occurs, and also to catch yours. They wouldn't occur at the same time, because for your exception to be thrown, the PDO operation must have completed without throwing an exception of its own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple catch blocks

```
catch(PDOException $pdo) { 
    echo $pdo;
}
catch(Exception $e) { 
    echo $e;
}
```

Or you can still keep one catch block and take help from **[instanceof](http://php.net/instanceof)**

```
catch(Exception $e) { 
    if($e instanceof PDOException)
        // pdoexception
    else
       // others
}
```

Comment: Do you mean one `try` and two `catch`s ? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible

Comment: Cool .. thx +1 ..!